# How do we convert decimal numbers into a categorical variables

Tags: r, data-science, data-wrangling

This is the code , which I tried out:

```
new_data_2[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.8 , 4]  = "A"
new_data_2[[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.6, 4] & new_data_2[new_data_2$X1998 < 0.8, 4]] = "B"
new_data_2[[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.4, 4] && new_data_2[new_data_2$X1998 < 0.6, 4]] = "C"
new_data_2[[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.2 , 4] && new_data_2[new_data_2$X1998 <= 0.4, 4]] = "D"
```

But I get the following error

```
Error: unexpected '&' in "new_data_2[[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.6, 4] &"
```

Comment: Put all the conditions in the same subset call `new_data_2[new_data_2$X1998 > 0.6 & new_data_2$X1998 < 0.8, 4] = "B"`.

Comment: with `cut` or `findInterval`

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks a ton, this one worked. I overcomplicated the code